# Rails Tutorial Ch. 3 Rspec failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

I am currently doing the Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, and I am now on Chapter 3. H At the end, after using the layouts, provide, and yield, the test should be successful, however, I am getting 3 failures everytime.

I put this in to test it:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

And I get this back:

```
'Failures:

1) StaticPages About page should have the title 'About Us'
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About  Us")
   expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) StaticPages Help page should have the title 'Help'
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
   expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) StaticPages Home page should have the title 'Home'
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
   expected #has_title?("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home") to return true, got false
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.24723 seconds
6 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:31 # StaticPages About page should have the title 'About Us'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:20 # StaticPages Help page should have the title 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:9 # StaticPages Home page should have the    title 'Home'

Randomized with seed 17890'
```

I simply cannot figure out the problem.

Here is my layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ruby on Rails Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my home:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
  This is the home page for the <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> sample application.
</p>
```

Here is my help:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Help') %>
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>
  Get help on the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at the <a href="http://railstutorial.org/help">Rails Tutorial help page</a>.
  To get help on this sample app, see the <a href="http://railstutorial.org/book">Rails Tutorial book</a>
</p>
```

Here is my about:

```
<% provide(:title, 'About Us') %>
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>
  The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

And my gemfile, if needed:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.8'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:   https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20',  require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Hopefully, someone can help me because I've exhausted all of my ideas of what could be wrong. Perhaps I'm missing something. Thank you to anyone who can answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<title>Ruby on Rails Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

to

```
<title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
```

as this is what you are testing for with rspec.